# Magento 2.3.1 CE emai to friend not working

Tags: magento2, customer, email, email-translation

We have upgrade from Magento 2.2.3 CE to Magento 2.3.1 CE but Email to friend not working (recipient not receiving email).

Verified logs using tail command

```
tail -f var/log/debug.log

tail -f var/log/exception.log

tail -f var/log/sytem.log
```

No luck. please advise